# Best way to loop through mapping

Tags: solidity

I have a voting contract and I am trying to find out the best way to get the winner key. Here is my code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Voting {
  mapping (int => uint8) public votesReceived;
  int[5] candidateList = [int(0),1,2,3,4];
  uint[] votes;

  function totalVotesFor(int candidate) view public returns (uint8) {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    return votesReceived[candidate];
  }

  function voteForCandidate(int candidate) public {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    votesReceived[candidate] += 1;
  }

  function validCandidate(int candidate) view public returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++) {
      if (candidateList[i] == candidate) {
        votes.push(votesReceived[candidate]);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

votesReceived keeps track of number of votes that each candidate has received but I am unable to figure out a way to get the key with most votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over a `mapping` so you also can't directly find out its contents.

But I guess you've already noticed this and you have a separate `array` with the candidate IDs. So what you can do is simply iterate over the `candidateList` and check how many votes each candidate has in their mapping and get the one with highest votes.

If this causes performance issues (as it definitely will with bigger amount of candidates) you can improve performance by updating a separate variable which keeps track of which candidate has the most votes (and how many) so every time someone votes you check if the total votes for that candidate exceed the previous high and you can update the data.

Furthermore your `validCandidate` looks rather strange and the contract wouldn't even compile - variable `votes` doesn't exist.

Comment: Really sorry about that. I edited my code to have votes array. I can loop through candidateList and look for votesReceived[n] but what's the best way to find out the max/min in solidity?

Comment: There is no built-in functionality for finding min/max. You just have to loop through and keep track of which is the max/min.